# Less variables scopes/contexts

Tags: css, less

My less code is something like this:

```
body {
  @var: white;

  &.blue { @var: blue; }
  &.red { @var: red; }
  &.abc { @var: #badass; }

  background-color: @var;
}
```

What I hope is, if the `body` has the class `.abc` the value of the variable `@var` is `#badass`, if you have the class `.blue` The value is `blue` and so on. But that's not what happens, the value of the variable dont change independent of their remains classes.

Comment: How should Less know what class you attach to your body tag?

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible! You are creating a CSS file with LESS. That has nothing to do with your HTML. How can LESS ever know what class you have assigned to your body tag in your mark up?

Comment: I am confused by your comments. CSS / LESS know the classes that I added to my body, that's not my problem.

Comment: My problem is probably that I can not see any use case where you want assign variables like that. Can you give me an explanation why you want to do that?

Comment: @Amb That's two different things. Oswaldo tried to create 4 delcarations "background-color" with different colors which is completey independent to which class the element has in the HTML. He just wanted a shorter way of writing.

Comment: @Christoph: I think what Oswaldo was trying to do was checking what class the body tag in his HTML document actually had and assigning a variable accordingly.

Comment: He's right @Christoph. Cause LESS is preprocessed. He'll never know which classes possess my body, to set the value of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a parametric mixin for that:

```
.bg(@color){
  background-color:@color;
}
```

and then the following code will work:

```
body {
  .bg("white");

  &.blue{ .bg("blue");  }
  &.red { .bg("red");   }
  &.abc { .bg(#bada55); }

}
```

What you are doing isn't working, because you are reassigning the variable - which works perfectly, but not writing the new value to the class. (It would make absolutely no sense if LESS created new rules, every time you are just reassigning a variable.) Also, like any other programming language, LESS has scope, thus at the time it reaches `background-color: @var;` `@var` has the value `white` assigned to it and creates the rule accordingly. This following will work (but makes no sense of course):

```
body {
  @var: white;

  &.blue{ @var: blue;    background-color: @var;}
  &.red { @var: red;     background-color: @var;}
  &.abc { @var: #bada55; background-color: @var;}
  background-color: @var;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this, but I wonder if it possible to do something like the above code in LESS. But thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @Oswaldo I've edited my answer to explain why your try didn't work.

Comment: Thx, now i understand why dont work.. I was thinking that the scope was given as in other programmming languages, something like this code:


`var abc = 'white';
 if($('body').hasClass('blue')){ abc = 'blue' }
$('body').css('background-color',abc);`

Comment: @OswaldoAcauan: This is what I was trying to say in my other comments. LESS can not know what class the body actually has on your website.

Comment: Now i understand your comments @Amberlamps :)

Comment: @Amberlamps hehe, now I understand too. I was not noticing that Oswaldo actually confused the whole process of how the less files are processed :-D